# D3 undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a barchart using d3, but I keep getting the "undefined is not a function" as a result of `.domain(dataset.map(function(d, i) {
            return d.year;
        }));`

The following is the whole code:

```
    var dataset = d3.csv('gp.csv', function(d) {
    return {
        year: +d.year,
        close: +d.close
    };
}, function(error, rows) {
    console.log(rows);
});

var maxCount = d3.max(dataset, function(d, i) {
            return d.close;
    });

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')

var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(dataset);

var newRects = rects.enter();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, 900])
        .domain([0, maxCount]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, 1200])
        .domain(dataset.map(function(d, i) {
            return d.year;
        }));

newRects.append('rect')
  .attr('x', x(0))
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return y(d.year);
  })
  .attr('height', y.rangeBand())
  .attr('width', function(d, i) {
    return x(d.close);
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure `dataset` is an array? Learn to use browser devtools.

Comment: You have to put you code that uses `dataset` inside the csv callback function... where you have `console.log(rows)`